# How to do remove the last occurrence of a string from another string?

Tags: c, string, glib, standard-library

Say I have to remove the *last occurrence* of a string from another string. How would I go about it?

To elaborate, I have a file name in a c string (gchar* or char* )

> *C:\SomeDir\SomeFolder\MyFile.pdf*

and I want to remove the extension *.pdf* , and change it to something else, e.g *.txt* or *.png* . What is the least troublesome yet efficient , convenient and cross-platform way to do it? Thanks.

***note***: I know this is an extremely simple thing to do in C++ but for this project , I absolutely MUST use C and no other language. (academic requirement)

***note 2***: Although you can suggest other third-party library , I currently only have access to the C standard library and the GLib.

***note 3***: I have searched for similar questions with the "C" tag, but can't seem to find any.

Comment: Will extensions always be 3 charachters long (you example indicates that) and will they always be at the end of the path? What encoding is your source string in? If its regular ASCII you could do `memcpy(source[strlen(source) - 4 /* count for \0 */], new_ext /* 3 chars + \0*/, 4);`

Comment: @RedX For my program, the filename will be entered as a command line argument so I am not sure about the size of the extensions. e.g what if someone passes a *.aspx file? Yes the string is in ASCII and the extension will always be at the end of the path.

Comment: Then i'd say reverse search the string for the last dot, subtract that from the length of the input and create a new string with the correct extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char fil[] = "C:\\SomeDir\\SomeFolder\\MyFile.pdf";
char fil2[1000];
char extension[] = ".tmp";

// search for . and add new extension
sprintf(fil2, "%s%s", strtok(fil, "."), extension);
printf("%s\n", fil2);
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look at basename.

```
NAME
dirname, basename - Parse pathname components

SYNOPSIS
#include <libgen.h>

char *dirname(char *path);
char *basename(char *path);

DESCRIPTION
Warning: there are two different functions basename() - see below.
The functions dirname() and basename() break a null-terminated
pathname string into directory and filename components. In the
usual case, dirname() returns the string up to, but not including,
the final â€™/â€™, and basename() returns the component following the
final â€™/â€™. Trailing â€™/â€™ characters are not counted as part of the
pathname.
```

Comment: Indent your code by four spaces (or highlight it and press the "code" formatting button) so that it is formatted like code. Also, you can Google and paste a link to a manpage much easier (and nicer-looking) than copying-and-pasting data directly from a manpage, but neither action makes for a really good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would normally use the "splitpath" function to seperate all four parts of a full path name (dir, path, name, ext).
Best regards 
Oliver

Answer (score 1):

Just modifying the above 'strtok' code with 'strrchr' function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_PATH 255

int main() 
{
  char f[MAX_PATH] = "dir\\file.pdf";
  char f1[MAX_PATH];
  char ext[] = ".tmp";
  char *ptr = NULL;
  // find the last occurance of '.' to replace
  ptr = strrchr(f, '.');
  // continue to change only if there is a match found
  if (ptr != NULL) {
    snprintf(f1, (ptr-f)+1, "%s", f);
    strcat(f1, ext);
  }
  printf("%s\n", f1);
  return 1;
}
```